# Why vs what for phrase construction?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Consider the two expressions,

> Why did you do that?

> What did you do that for?

I use the above two expressions interchangeably. Are they both identical in meaning?

Comment: Yes, they both question the reason that someone did something.